# Querying Cloudant by property instead of getting all docs with Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, couchdb, cloudant

I'm building an app using Angular, PHP and Cloudant.

Right now I just query all docs and then deal/filter/display the data using Angular, but I get the feeling that this will get close to bad practice when the amount of documents increase.

Considering the current code, how could I query by a document property instead of getting all docs?

Angular code:

```
var $promisedbex=$http.get('databaseconnect/getalldiscovery.php'); 

$promisedbex.then(function (data) {
    $scope.dataex = [];
    $scope.dataex = data.data.rows;
    console.log($scope.dataex);
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://user:pass@user.cloudant.com/discovery/_all_docs?include_docs=true";
    $ch = curl_init();   // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Document example:

```
{
  "_id": "1339ede5175888cb31e7f96aabd296bf",
  "_rev": "1-7dc3fd24ce2a3846fcbae0e47daab829",
  "fair": "Koelner Liste",
  "fairyear": "2017"
}
```

How could I query by `fair` for instance?

Comment: You have to create view that emits the properties that you want to query. Look on google how to work with views. If you're using CouchDB 2.0, you can create indexes and use the Mango Query Selectors (which is a query language similar to MongoDB. It's more flexible than views).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view that uses `fair` as its key.  This will enable you to limit and/or sort results using this key as the basis.  The map function might look like:

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.fair, null);
}
```

When fetching the data from the view, still use the `include_docs` parameter, and consider also using `startkey` and `endkey` to filter as neeeded.